# Rails search form doesn't work if page has another form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, search

I have a search form in my navbar, so it's on all pages of the application. If i go to a page that has a form like the user's edit page or create a new post page the search doesn't work. How come?? How can i fix this??

**EDIT (read comments)**

```
// Make sure search form isn't blank
$("form.navbar-search").submit(function(){
    var isFormValid = true;

    $("input").each(function(){
        if ($.trim($(this).val()).length == 0){
            isFormValid = false;
        }
        else{
            $(this).removeClass("highlight");
        }
    });

    return isFormValid;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There could be a million reasons, and you haven't given us much to go on.  What do you mean by "doesn't work"?  Do you get JS errors in your browser console?  Application errors in your Rails log?

Comment: That comment actually helped me out. I put a javascript function to prevent people from searching nil (when they just click enter without searching anything). for some reason this was messing up on certain pages...I'll put the javascript in my first post with an EDIT, but i'll figure out a better javascript function that works on all pages...

Comment: Alright i updated the javascript and its working now...thanks for the tip @jeremy